# HDRI with ND Filter

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, exposure, hdr

When I take images for composing a HDR image later how can I use an ND-Filter.
For example I capture 5 images whitout an Filter and then add for the 6 and 7 shot a 10 Stop ND-Filter how can I tell the composing software (in my case Lightroom) that I used a 10 Stop-ND filter for the last two images.

AFAIK Lighroom needs to know the Exposure value of every pixel for composing a HDR image. And the exposure value would be wrong if I use a ND-Filter since the camera "does not know" about the filter and cant write it into metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom should have somewhere you can type in the EV.  If it doesn't, you can use ExifTool to set it.

```
exiftool -exposurecompensation=-10 image.ext
```